# update and delete in realm xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

i have a following json that i am Add and Update in realm database

JSON

```
"listActivityTypeMaster": [
    {
        "id": "NV_22_06",
        "name": "NV_22_06"
    },
    {
        "id": "POC",
        "name": "POC"
    }
]
```

class that stores above json

```
public class ActivityType : RealmObject, IEntity
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }


}
```

to create and update  i am using following realm statement

```
realm.WriteAsync(tempRealm =>{


    tempRealm.Add(data, true);


});
```

Now what i want is if my JSON gets changed by removing one entry then my realm should also delete that entry when i fire `tempRealm.Add(data, true);`

```
"listActivityTypeMaster": [

    {
        "id": "POC",
        "name": "POC"
    }
]
```

i do understand that `tempRealm.Add(data, true);` is for updating record and it will add a new entry of primary key does not exist otherwise it will replace it.
but is there any way if primary key is not exist then it will delete that record from realm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, and there are very few cases where that would be desirable. As a workaround, after updating, you can execute:

```
var activities = realm.All<ActivityType>().ToArray();
var ids = new HashSet<string>(data.Select(d => d.id));
realm.Write(() =>
{
    foreach (var activity in activities)
    {
        if (!ids.Contains(activity.Id))
        {
            realm.Remove(activity);
        }
    }
});
```